# How to make heroku play nice with sequelize.js + postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, deployment, sequelize.js

I'm most of the way there, has anyone gotten it to succesfully work? I only have the database working locally, after I git push heroku master the connection to the database fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add 'Heroku Postgres' either through the Heroku CLI or under your project's Resources tab. It should also give you a `DATABASE_URL` variable which you need for later.
2. Add pg module from Heroku. See the documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js).

   ```
   $ npm install --save --save-exact pg
   ```

   Then, on the server, use the `DATABASE_URL` we just got.

   ```
   const client = new Client({
     connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
     ssl: true,
   });

   client.connect();
   ```
3. Put `"use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"` on the `config.json` file under "production". Should look like

   ```
   "production": {
       "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"
       ...
   }
   ```
4. Run migrations on Heroku. An option if you want to use sequelize-cli is:

   ```
   $ npm install sequelize-cli --save
   $ heroku run sequelize db:migrate
   ```

And it should work.